# Button with column for child not using align

Tags: flutter

I'm attempting to layout some buttons in a flutter app towards the bottom of the screen as seen here:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('images/foo.jpeg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover),
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          child: _buttonsOne(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(''),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
          child: _buttonsTwo(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Counter buttons is setup thusly:

```
Widget _buttonsTwo() {
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: <Widget>[
    _oneButton(),
    _twoButton(),
    _threeButton(),
    _fourButton()
  ],
);
```

}

My problem is two of the buttons are using glyphs that cause them to be just right of center. Prior to attempting this layout I structured raised buttons with columns so that I could use an Align to pull these icons to the left a bit, as seen here for one of the buttons:

```
Widget _threeButton() {
return RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  elevation: 10,
  color: Colors.red,
  textColor: Colors.white,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment(-0.4, 0),
        child: Icon(
          Class.icon_name,
          size: 30,
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        _fooCount.toString(),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

And here's the result I'm getting:

[image]

As you can see, the icons for the two rightmost buttons are still a little to the right. I've tried using `RaisedButton.icon` to no avail as it causes the icons to overlap the text, even restructuring them in a row to try and make wider buttons. What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, could you add a minimum sample code to run your sample?

Comment: Might be hard given the icons I'm using are custom, so you'd need to download those. I can try to provide more of my code if that'll work?

Comment: oh ok, so the problem are the icons

Comment: Just these two it would seem. In an earlier build of my app before I started laying things out more how I wanted them, I was able to use the Align class in the columns for these buttons without a problem. Ever since putting them in this layout the Align doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you swipe the 2 icons from left to the right and check if they are looking good?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I have, and they do align themselves properly, though the Align class isn't factoring in here. I swap them with the icons on the left and then try to make adjustments with the Align class and they still don't move, even after fully rebuilding my app.

Comment: @diegoveloper I uploaded my project to GitHub if you'd like to pull it down. https://github.com/degoeym/l5r_companion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Transform` widget instead of `Align` and translate the X axis:

```
    Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.identity()..translate(-7.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    FiveRingsDB.conflict_political,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  _militaryCount.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                )
```

Comment: This does indeed appear to work! What's so different about this compared to a more simple Align, though?

Comment: Align it's a widget to that aligns its child within itself and optionally sizes itself based on the child's size.  Transform just 'transform' the widget before painting. In this case you are limited by the size of the child so you can't align the widget.